# Android - Broadcast Receiver screen off to Intent, not working....?

Tags: java, android

I have code below that I have inserted into my onCreate method, but it dosent seem to work.
I want it to launch other activity when screen goes off/battery button press.

CODE:

```
protected void onStartCommand() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    ScreenReceiver();
}

 public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

                lock.reenableKeyguard();        
                Intent s = new Intent(Activity1.this , Activity2.class); 
                startActivity(s);


            } 
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                lock.disableKeyguard(); 



            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be VERY appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to acquire a `WakeLock` before you try starting that Activity.

Refer to CommonsWare answer here
[android AlarmManager not waking phone up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864712/android-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up)

Comment: And don't forget to release the WakeLock at the appropriate time