# Why no push notification or some notification for incoming messages in the screen when the phone is in locked state? on Galaxy note

Tags: android, push-notification, galaxy

i am using Samsung Galaxy Note. When my phone is in locked state, and when i click the power button i see the pattern unlocking screen. When new messages flow in, i just see a mail icon in the top status bar, but no other notifications in the screen. what needs to be done for that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wakeup the device when push message came.

onMesaage method of GCM service you have to call below code

```
public abstract class WakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context ctx) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, MainActivity.APP_TAG);
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

See the below link

[android AlarmManager not waking phone up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864712/android-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up?rq=1)