# AlarmManager not working when phone is locked

Tags: android

`AlarmManager` does not start my broadcast receiver when phone is locked for example. I search and try many solutions but none works:

```
 AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent i = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

      mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                        PERIOD,
                        pi);
```

but `OnAlarmReceiver` is never fired!

I also try with `WakeLock`:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();
// code
wl.release();
 }
```

but also not working. why?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` added in manifest file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6865323/1339473 @senzacionale check this i think that will worked

Comment: could you please post complete code that work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but OnAlarmReceiver is never fired!

It should be. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful) showing a similar use of `AlarmManager` that works perfectly fine when the screen is off and the phone is locked. In my sample, the "real work" is done by a `WakefulIntentService`, by means of a `BroadcastReceiver`, so the `BroadcastReceiver` is definitely getting control.

Comment: thanky you. I change OnBootReceiver for example to OnScreenChangeReceiver but later OnAlarmReceiver is never called. I am runing OnScreenReceiver like:

`final IntentFilter intentScreenfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentScreenfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
screenReceiver = new OnScreenReceiver();

// Register the receiver so that your service will listen for broadcast
registerReceiver(screenReceiver, intentScreenfilter);`

Comment: and i can see this in log: `12-10 16:36:00.000: E/AlarmManagerService(1990): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 1195102.441000000
12-10 16:36:00.015: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1990): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
12-10 16:36:00.020: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1990): handleTimeUpdate
12-10 16:36:00.045: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(2107): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
D/STATUSBAR-Clock(2107): updateClock :16:36
 D/STATUSBAR-DateView(2107): updateClock :
D/DigitalClock(23824): DigitalClockAppWidgetService. action :  android.intent.action.TIME_TICK`

Comment: and how to stop AlarmManager in your example?

Comment: @senzacionale: You can call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` to cancel an alarm, passing in an equivalent `PendingIntent` for the one you scheduled as an alarm.

Comment: Thank you. and what about error? my receiver is never fired. I always get error:  E/AlarmManagerService(1990): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=x

Comment: @senzacionale: I have no idea.