# How to do scheduling in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a scheduler app in android in which i want to run app in background daily on an specified time.Below is the code but this is not working for me Please suggest

```
  private void setAlarm(String targetCal){
    String[] Time=targetCal.split(":");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
    //int days = Calendar.SUNDAY + (7 - timeOff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // how many days until Sunday
    timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR,Integer.valueOf(Time[0]));
    timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.valueOf(Time[1]));
    timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: try System.getTimeInMillis() instead of timeoff.getTimeInMillis()

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure of the reason why it doesn't work based on your description, but my guess is that you are not acquiring a `WakeLock` in `AlarmReceiver`'s `onReceive()` method.

I posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864712/android-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up) some time ago, while I was trying to implement something similar. Check out the accepted answer and the answer from CommonsWare. I hope they will prove useful in solving your problem.

Regards!