# Call service at specific time in android

Tags: android

I have service run in background.
I want to call this service at specific interval.
if user provide values 10, 20, 30 than service should call after 10 min,20 min and 30 min receptively.

How can I do above thing?

Comment: Use alarmmanager to fire your service. Search for alarm manager and you will get numerous examples.

Comment: but alarm manager calls twice. first when i set alarm and another time after provided delay. I want to call only one time. i.e. if i have call setalarm at 10:20:25 and provide time for 5 sec than it trigges two times at 10:20:25 and 10:20:30.

Comment: Post your alarm code.. You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017471/786337

Answer (score 1):

[`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) will help you :)

It allows you to set up a schedule to launch your application's components during the specified time range

## Update

To instantiate an `AlarmManager` that will go into play at the specific period after it's instantiating, configure it with `setRepeating()` method and PERIOD parameter added to `SystemClock.elapsedRealime()`:

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                     SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + PERIOD, PERIOD, pi); // Here PERIOD is a value specified by you as PendingIntent object
```

Comment: but alarm manager calls twice. first when i set alarm and another time after provided delay. I want to call only one time. i.e. if i have call setalarm at 10:20:25 and provide time for 5 sec than it trigges two times at 10:20:25 and 10:20:30.

Comment: It will not be called twice if you configure it with `setRepeating()` with specified `triggerAtMillis` parameter which could be an offset from the time you instantiate your `AlarmManager`

Comment: See my update answer. You should also consider recommendations from the official documentation about starting `Service` objects which says that >> If your alarm receiver called Context.startService(), it is possible that the phone will sleep before the requested service is launched. To prevent this, your BroadcastReceiver and Service will need to implement a separate wake lock policy to ensure that the phone continues running until the service becomes available.

Comment: am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
    1000 * 5, pi); what should I pass insted of System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Well, at least you should increase the second parameter (`triggerAtMillis`) `System.currentTimeMillis()` value by 5 seconds to trigger `AlarmManager` 5 seconds after it was instantiated

Answer (score 0):

You can set an [Alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to have an Intent fired at specific interval. You can also set an inexact alarm if it is not critical that the alarm runs at the precise time.

Comment: but alarm manager calls twice. first when i set alarm and another time after provided delay. I want to call only one time. i.e. if i have call setalarm at 10:20:25 and provide time for 5 sec than it trigges two times at 10:20:25 and 10:20:30

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 25);

        Intent dailyQuotes = new Intent(getActivity(), DailyQuotesService.class);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, dailyQuotes, 0);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), 30000, pi);
```

here is my code and it call my service exactly on specified time. and then is repeated every 30 secs.