# AlarmManager not work if screen off

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My app use AlarmManager.
I try next code for create Alarm

```
public void startAlarm(int timeInterval){
    if (timeInterval == -1)
        return;
    int id = generateIdAlarmManager();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(id, timeInterval * 60000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        final AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval * 60000, pendingIntent);

        manager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval * 60000, pendingIntent);
    else
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval * 60000, pendingIntent);

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putInt(ALARM_MANAGER_ID_ALARM_CHECK_SMS, id);
    edit.putInt(ALARM_MANAGER_INTERVAL_CHECK_SMS, timeInterval);
    edit.putBoolean(ALARM_MANAGER_ENABLE_CHECK_SMS, true);
    edit.apply();
    edit.commit();
}
```

AlarmManager working if screen on. If screen off AlarmManager not working.
I add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864712/-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up) using the **WakeLock** object.

*More information about WaveLock in [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html):*

> A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to
>   have the device stay on.

Answer (score 1):

call

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),timeIntervalForBroadcast, pendingIntent)
```

instead of manager.set() method of alaramManager.

Comment: This solution is not working.
I try such code
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   System.currentTimeMillis(), timeInterval * 60000, pendingIntent);